# How can I display the German Umlaut (ä, ö, ü) using the Hiero Tool in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx

I am using the Hiero Tool in libGDX in order to pack and use fonts in my libGDX game. My game should also have a German version, but I cannot find any font that can display the German Umlaute (ä, ö, ü) when I run my game. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Hiero to add almost any character (included chinese ones) and the requisite were:

- The source font must have these characters (you can make test with system fonts)
- The source font must be .tff (or a system font). If you use anything else some characters might not display
- Rendering should be "Free type"
- You need to add these characters to your new font ("Sample text" field)
- Use the radio button "Glyph cache" to show if your new font fits on
  one page (make the page width or height bigger if not). I don't
  remember if its mandatory, but what I can rembember is that I had
  some problems that I avoided when I just fit them on one page (check the view
  combo,if it has onlye the option of have Page 1 it's done)

[image: Example chinese. Works with any character]

Then in your code just load the font (save it first, it will create two files, one png and one fnt) with:

```
BitmapFont fontCN;
Texture textureCN = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Fonts/cn.png"), true);
textureCN.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

fontCN = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/Fonts/cn.fnt"), new TextureRegion(textureCN), false);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. I understood and checked any of the requisites you listed above. However, I cannot find any original font that has the German Umlaute in the Hiero Tool.

Comment: Well, when I said "original font" I meant "source font". You can use any System font (like Arial) where you (probably) are going to have all the characters you need. (Please be aware of possible licensing issues of modifying third party fonts, but at least you can test that what you want to do is possible). I edited the post to make it clearer